# SQL count those who expired

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

Im trying to find the total of those who have a membership type platinum. This is what i came up with but its not working.

```
SELECT COUNT (MType_ID=Platinum)
FROM Membership
WHERE (((Membership.MType_ID)=Platinum));
```

Comment: what the error code that return to you??

Comment: Its still giving me the "Enter Parameter Value" box, The logic seems absolutely right.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM Membership
WHERE Membership.MType_ID='Platinum';
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
SELECT COUNT (MType_ID='Platinum')
FROM Membership
WHERE Membership.MType_ID = Platinum;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the total using sum() as below.

```
SELECT sum(MType_ID='Platinum')
FROM Membership
```

If you want can also use an alias for the total as

```
SELECT sum(MType_ID='Platinum') as total_platinum
    FROM Membership
```